# Why foldl1 fails applying the (==) operator?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, higher-order-functions, fold

From **prelude**:

> **foldl1**: it takes the first 2 items of
>   the list and applies the function to
>   them, then feeds the function with
>   this result and the third argument and
>   so on.

Why is not possible to write something like this?

```
foldl1 (==) [6, 6, 6]
foldl1 (\x y -> x == y) [6, 6, 6]
```

Comment: Just a hunch but applying the equality operator on the first two yields a boolean.  I doubt it makes any sense to compare a boolean to an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Antal points out that my reasoning was incorrect. Here is the relevant part of the comment that gives the real reasoning (I feel bad taking this verbatim, but this answer was accepted so I can't delete it):

The reason this doesn't work is that the type of `foldl1` is `(a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a`, but the type of `(==)` is `Num a => a -> a -> Bool`. Since `Bool` isn't a `Num`, `(==)` type doesn't match `a -> a -> a`, and so the application of `foldl1` is rejected. If it were accepted, you'd end up with a situation where you were trying to do `True == 6`, but the type system never gets you get that far in the first place.

Original answer (latter reasoning incorrect):

`==` will take two `Int`s and return a `Bool`. After the first iteration your example list becomes `[True, 6]`. It then tries to compare `True` to `6` which fails.

Comment: Your first sentence is correct, but True is not cast to 1 in Haskell!

Comment: @marcog: thanks, it makes perfect sense. Shame on me not thinking about it! :)

Comment: @drvitek Thanks. My practical haskell isn't strong.

Comment: marcog: No worries - this is a good note if OP ever recreates this functionality in another language and wonders why, for example, this code would give incorrect results on [6,6,1].  I would hate to track down that bug...

Comment: This still isn't quite right.  The list `[True,6]` can't exist in Haskell, because it's ill-typed; even if it could, this would make things fail at runtime, not compile-time.  The reason this doesn't work is that the type of `foldl1` is `(a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a`, but the type of `(==)` is `Num a => a -> a -> Bool`.  Since `Bool` isn't a `Num`, `(==)` type doesn't match `a -> a -> a`, and so the application of `foldl1` is rejected.  If it *were* accepted, you'd end up with a situation where you were trying to do `True == 6`, but the type system never ets you get that far in the first place.

Comment: @Antal Thanks for that explanation. Pity OP just accepted my answer, because now I can't delete it. So I added your reasoning pretty much verbatim. If you post your comment as a separate answer, I'll flag this for a mod to delete if that's possible so that you get the credit.

Comment: @marcog: Don't worry about it—the answer's right now, which is the important thing.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check if all of the elements of a list are equal, a quick solution is

```
allEqual [] = True --(edit: this case is not necessary as pointed out by sepp2k)
allEqual xs = all (== head xs) xs
```

Somebody will write a more elegant way to do this, I am sure, but this is serviceable.

Edit: Thanks to sepp2k for the suggestions.

Comment: No need for the first case since `and []` is true anyway. Also `and . map` is `all`.

Comment: sepp2k: I updated after I realized that without seeing your comment first.  I guess we were thinking of the same thing.  It is clever to realize that the first case is not needed, however; I was thinking that `head` would fail in this case

Comment: It would if it were evaluated. But if `xs` is empty, `all` never calls the function, so `head` never needs to be evaluated.

Comment: @sepp2k: Yep, I realized that after puzzling over your comment for a while.  It appears I have yet to fully let lazy thinking take over...

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version:

```
allEqual xs = and $ zipWith (==) xs (tail xs)
```

Comment: Inspired by your answer, there's also this: `allEqual xs = tail xs == init xs`

Comment: @Dan: You might want to use drop 1 instead of tail, so this will work on empty lists as well.

Comment: Wouldn't help, because in that case it fails when calling `init`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a fold, I would suggest this modification:

```
allEqual xs = foldr (\x acc -> x == head xs && acc) True xs
```

This is very similar to the already-suggested `all` approach. Note that both this and the `all` approach can work on infinite lists (as long as the answer is `False`).

For very long finite lists, in very rare cases you might get better performance out of a strict left fold:

```
allEqual xs = foldl' (\acc x -> acc && x == head xs) True xs
```

But the right fold is generally better for this problem, since (in this implementation) it only performs a number of folding steps equal to `length $ takeWhile (== head xs) xs`. The left fold will perform `length xs` folding steps every time.

Comment: You can write `allEqual xs = foldl' (flip $ (&&).(== head xs)) True xs` for better obfuscation.